# React-bootstrap NavBar and components positioning using css issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I learn Reactjs and Javascript and now I have this react-bootstrap `NavBar` and wonder how to make this search input component move closer to the image. I hade a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-reactbootsrap-navbar-2-with-media-query-qy8m1?file=/src/components/elements/NavBar.jsx:860-865)

I use Media Queries but cant understand why the logo image take up(push) all space so the search input cant move to the left and center nicely. I set media Queries breakpoints at 1410px, 1216px, 992px and try to handle it in css but I cant find css details at [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) for this.
Please advice

I know the react-bootstrap `fluid` will evenly space out Components but are there some why to get finer grain control for positioning when screen size
change?

Maybe I ask to much from React-bootstrap or there is some better library or way to do this?

This red ring I wrote here show the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gap between logo and search text box seems to be a result of having a width 60%.

```
.logo {
width: 60%;
}
```

Try remove above width and adjust logo image width from it's wrapper anchor. Like below

```
.container-fluid {
 .navbar-brand {
  max-width: 28%; // adjust this size as you please
 }
}
```

refer [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-reactbootsrap-navbar-2-with-media-query-forked-6287s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: You're a magician Thanks!! I learn so much! Can I ask where I can read about this css stuff. The react-boostrap docs dont have this what I can see

Comment: Happy to help. Follow related articles on platforms such as medium.com and dev.to

Comment: Thanks moving on it works grate but just a little [snatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198047/using-media-query-in-css-does-not-work-under-width-768px-in-this-codesandbox), cant get it to work under 768px