# Using Media Query in css does not work under width 768px in this CodeSandbox

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, navbar, react-bootstrap

I use media query in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-reactbootsrap-navbar-3-under-768px-not-working-jnsev?file=/src/styles/navbar.scss) and it works as expected for all but `768px`. When screen width go under 768px I cant adjust any css like I did for all above width's. The `NavBar` `FormControl` search input as image below show cant be resized in css for some reason please advice?
**NOTE: set browser window to 100% zoom in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-reactbootsrap-navbar-3-under-768px-not-working-jnsev?file=/src/styles/navbar.scss) for this to work!**

```
@media (min-width: 1410px) {
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
@media (min-width: 992px) {
@media (min-width: 768px) {
@media (min-width: 576px) {
```

At 768px:

[image]

Under 768px

[image]

Comment: if you are on a wide display of say 1410px it will pass the first test, it will pass the second test and will pass the final test. If you are on a display of width 768px it will pass the penultimate test and then it will pass the last test. Are your tests in reverse order of what they need to be?

Comment: @AHaworth Do you mean in the css I should have 1410px first and 576px last?

Comment: @AHaworth I changed order of them in the css and now nothings works no css

Comment: We probably need to see more of your CSS to see what the problem is. For example, what are your CSS settings before the media CSS - what is the default setting for devices with even smaller widths?

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth I did some advances and created a new [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205043/react-boostrap-navbar-formcontrol-and-buttons-how-to-control-left-alignment-and) about Media Queries