# React-boostrap NavBar FormControl and Buttons how to control left alignment and size in fluid layout

Tags: reactjs, layout, navbar, react-bootstrap

I learn rectjs and use the [react-bootstrap NavBar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/). I use the suggest breakpoints from [Media Queries docs](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/layout/media-queries/) and it looks like this:

Here is my Media Queries breakpoints:

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
```

I made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-reactbootsrap-navbar-3-under-768px-not-working-jnsev?file=/src/styles/navbar.scss)

**NOTE: set browser window to 100% zoom in the CodeSandbox for this to work!**

My problem is when I resize window and get under width `905px`. Then I can't fine grain control layout in css so layout starting to wrap:

**This is how it should look:**

[image]

**Under 905px toggle button jumps down:**

[image]

**Under 758px it looks even more bad**
[image]

I try to change the css:

```
  .container-fluid { // THIS IS LOGO IMAGE
    .navbar-brand {
     max-width: 37%; 
    }
   }

  .form-inline { // THIS IS THE SEARCH INPUT
    width: 80%;
  }
```

The problem is I think that I can't move the SEARCH INPUT and the buttons to the left as the screen width gets lesser. Changing the `form-inline` width to lets say `40px` cuts it of only on the right side.
Any advice is helpful thanks?

**Moving the button to the left on this image would do the trick I guess but how?**

[image]

Comment: Hi, me again. I think we really do need to see your CSS in the media queries to know what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth,  In the question i added a css code in the  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-reactbootsrap-navbar-3-under-768px-not-working-jnsev?file=/src/styles/navbar.scss)

Comment: Thanks, seen it now. Its doing its best to keep things readable on a small screen. Have you considered changing the search form for a magnifying glass on the smaller screens which expands to a search box only if clicked? I realize this does not answer your question which implies you want to keep the search box as it is.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth yea it could be a good idea will try the magnifying glass. Do I need to in the code test like if(small screen) then show magnifying glass? Or can I in the css insert a magnifying glass in the Media Queries